# access the view but not the node

Tags: views, nodes, entities

I have a view that displays a list of items. How to make anonymous user see this list of items but when accessing the node, it has to be logged? Any idea?

I use the latest version of drupal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable node_access check for the view (Edit the View → *Advanced → Query settings → Disable SQL Rewriting*).

Answer (score -1):

you can also create a page and embed your view inside it. in this way users can see your view. also create a node page and check this condition

```
if($logged_in)
{
    //your code
 }
```

Comment: Hi, Mohammad I'm finally using what you say. But how to make if the user is authenticated not show me the rest of the node and show me another page?

Comment: Hi, I could not understand you, if the user is authenticated then your page in the bracket will be displayed. now this is my question: what is `the rest of the node` and what is `another page`? please clarify your question then I`ll be able to help you.

Answer (score -1):

in order to create a page for your view, I guess your view has a page display, set a path for it, say `/test` . now create a .php file and name it `page--test.tpl.php` and embed your view using this instruction :

```
views_embed_view('NAME_OF_YOUR_VIEW','page');
```

clear the cache and go to `/test` you will see your view.

and about your node page, there are couple of things you need to do, first in your template file add this function

```
function YourThemeName_preprocess_page(&$variables)
{

    if (isset($variables['node'])) 
    {
         if($variables['node']->type == "YourContentTypeName")
         {
                $suggest = "page__node__test";
                $variables['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = $suggest;
         }

    }
}
```

now create a .php file and rename it to `page--node--test.tpl.php`, this will be your node page and you can set authentication condition for it. you can even go further and check this authentication condition in your preprocess function, I mean create two different `$suggest`s in preprocess function :

```
function YourThemeName_preprocess_page(&$variables)
{

    if (isset($variables['node'])) 
    {
         if($variables['node']->type == "YourContentTypeName")
         {
                if($logged_in)
                {
                    $suggest = "page__node__test_authenticated";
                    $variables['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = $suggest;
                }
                else
                {
                        $suggest ="page__node__test_notAuthenticated";
                        $variables['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = $suggest;
                }

         }

    }
}
```

and now create two node pages in the same way I said, one for authenticated and one for non-Authenticated users. you can also get and set fields of your content type fields in preprocess function and display them in node page. don't forget to clear the chache